# Why using random forest to make sure my decision tree model doesn't overfit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

My Code :

```
# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Using random forest to make sure my model doesn't overfit

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 20) #n_esitmators value can be changed according to need
clf = clf.fit(ft,pima['brand'])
```

I want to know the best explanation about above application of random forest classifier in the code. what is the reason of using this random forest classifier in this time?

Comment: *what is the reason of using this random forest classifier in this time*, we can't tell a reason unless we know the data.

Comment: Are you asking why random forests are used over a single decision tree? That really isn't a question that is on-topic for Stack Overflow, which is for specific, programming questions. This is more of a theoretical machine learning question, probaby better suited for [statistics.se] although there are probably already many answers there about that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes! What is your question actually about? What's the end game here? Basically, the Random Forest algo consists is an ensemble of decision trees. A single decision tree is very sensitive to data variations. It can easily overfit to noise in the data. The Random Forest with only one tree will overfit to data as well because it is the same as a single decision tree.

When we add trees to the Random Forest then the tendency to overfitting should decrease (thanks to bagging and random feature selection). However, the generalization error will not go to zero. The variance of generalization error will approach to zero with more trees added but the bias will not!

Run the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Import CSV mtcars
data = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeccaLehn/4e06d2575eb9589dbe8c365d61cb056c/raw/64f1660f38ef523b2a1a13be77b002b98665cdfe/mtcars.csv')
# Edit element of column header
data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'brand'}, inplace=True)

X1= data.iloc[:,1:12]
Y1= data.iloc[:,-1]

#lets try to plot Decision tree to find the feature importance
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree= DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=1)
tree.fit(X1, Y1)

imp= pd.DataFrame(index=X1.columns, data=tree.feature_importances_, columns=['Imp'] )
imp.sort_values(by='Imp', ascending=False)

sns.barplot(x=imp.index.tolist(), y=imp.values.ravel(), palette='coolwarm')

X=data[['cyl','disp','hp','drat','wt','qsec','vs','am','gear','carb']]
y=data['mpg']

# split to train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)


rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_predicted = rf.predict(X_train)
y_test_predicted_full_trees = rf.predict(X_test)
mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predicted)
mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_predicted_full_trees)
print("RF with full trees, Train MSE: {} Test MSE: {}".format(mse_train, mse_test))


rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, min_samples_leaf=25)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_predicted = rf.predict(X_train)
y_test_predicted_pruned_trees = rf.predict(X_test)
mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predicted)
mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_predicted_pruned_trees)
print("RF with pruned trees, Train MSE: {} Test MSE: {}".format(mse_train, mse_test))


rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1)
for iter in range(50):
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_train_predicted = rf.predict(X_train)
    y_test_predicted = rf.predict(X_test)
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predicted)
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_predicted)
    print("Iteration: {} Train mse: {} Test mse: {}".format(iter, mse_train, mse_test))
    rf.n_estimators += 1


import graphviz
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn import tree

# To keep the size of the tree small, I set max_depth = 3.
# Fit the regressor, set max_depth = 3
regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, random_state=1234)
model = regr.fit(X, y)

# 1
text_representation = tree.export_text(regr)
print(text_representation)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(regr, feature_names=X.columns, filled=True)

# 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(regr, 
                   feature_names=X.columns,  
                   filled=True)
```

[image]